# NPM module (handontable) not installing sub-dependency(numbro) as project dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, handsontable

**What I am trying to do:**
So, I am installing a package which has a dependency `numbro` (another package).  For my use case, I need to use that package and initialize it with some value. (set default currency)

However, I am not able to use that package in my code. As from inspecting package-json.lock, I can see that the package isn't there as direct project dependency but is present inside handontable's dependencies.

I thought, I can add `numbro` directly inside my package.json file to initialize some values but from what it seems, adding it direct and setting default value there doesn't solves the issue.

To check further, I created a dummy angular project with only handontable and handontable/angular to see, if I can reproduce the issue there.  However,  after npm install, I could use `numbro` package in the dummy project and the reason being it was present as direct project dependency in package-json.lock file.

The versions of numbro, handontable, handontable/angular and angular are all same in both projects but why is it that in one project I can use the the sub-dependency in my angular project but in another I cannot ?

Original Project:
[image]

Dummy Fiddle project:
[image]
(installed as direct project dependency)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed it with some help from handsontable support team. I deleted node_modules folder and package-json.lock file both.

After which npm install did the trick.

I had tried deleting node_modules folder earlier but doing that alone doesn't resolved the issue.